Site not rendering because of NoSuchMethodError
Having a pom.xml like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>a</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>a</name>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean install javadoc:javadoc test site lesscss:compile</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.21.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asciidoctor-parser-doxia-module</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

A asciidoc like this (/src/site/asciidoc/a.adoc):
= Hi

And site.xml like this (/src/site/site.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.6.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.6.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.6.0.xsd">
    <skin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </skin>
</project>

I get a error:
C:\xxx\a>mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------------< a:a >---------------------------------
[INFO] Building a 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ a ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Projects2\a\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ a ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Projects2\a\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) @ a ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ a ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Projects2\a\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ a ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.2.5:test (default-test) @ a ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.4.1:jar (default-jar) @ a ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Projects2\a\target\a-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- install:3.1.2:install (default-install) @ a ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects2\a\pom.xml to C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\a\a\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\a-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects2\a\target\a-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\a\a\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\a-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> javadoc:3.11.1:javadoc (default-cli) > generate-sources @ a >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< javadoc:3.11.1:javadoc (default-cli) < generate-sources @ a <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- javadoc:3.11.1:javadoc (default-cli) @ a ---
[INFO] Skipping org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.11.1:javadoc report goal
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ a ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Projects2\a\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) @ a ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ a ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Projects2\a\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ a ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.2.5:test (default-test) @ a ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO]
[INFO] --- site:3.21.0:site (default-site) @ a ---
[WARNING] Input file encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Rendering site for default locale
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] Configuring report plugin maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.8.0
[INFO] Detected 15 reports for maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.8.0: ci-management, dependencies, dependency-info, dependency-management, distribution-management, index, issue-management, licenses, mailing-lists, modules, plugin-management, plugins, scm, summary, team
[WARNING] Site model of 'a:a:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' for default locale is still using the old pre-version 2.0.0 model. You MUST migrate to the new model as soon as possible otherwise your build will break in the future!
[WARNING] No project URL defined - site links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering content with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-fluido-skin:jar:2.0.0 skin
[INFO] Rendering 1 Doxia document: 1 asciidoc
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.742 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-22T13:41:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.21.0:site (default-site) on project a: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.21.0:site failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.21.0:site: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.maven.doxia.logging.Log org.asciidoctor.maven.site.parser.AsciidoctorAstDoxiaParser.getLog()'
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.21.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.21.0/maven-site-plugin-3.21.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-parser-doxia-module/3.0.0/asciidoctor-parser-doxia-module-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-commons/3.0.0/asciidoctor-maven-commons-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj/2.5.11/asciidoctorj-2.5.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj-api/2.5.11/asciidoctorj-api-2.5.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.82/jcommander-1.82.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby/9.4.5.0/jruby-9.4.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-base/9.4.5.0/jruby-base-9.4.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.2/asm-9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.2/asm-commons-9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.2/asm-tree-9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.2/asm-analysis-9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.2/asm-util-9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-netdb/1.2.0/jnr-netdb-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-enxio/0.32.16/jnr-enxio-0.32.16.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-unixsocket/0.38.21/jnr-unixsocket-0.38.21.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-posix/3.1.18/jnr-posix-3.1.18.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-constants/0.10.4/jnr-constants-0.10.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-ffi/2.2.15/jnr-ffi-2.2.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-a64asm/1.0.0/jnr-a64asm-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-x86asm/1.0.2/jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jffi/1.3.12/jffi-1.3.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jffi/1.3.12/jffi-1.3.12-native.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jruby/joni/joni/2.2.1/joni-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jcodings/jcodings/1.0.58/jcodings-1.0.58.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jruby/dirgra/0.3/dirgra-0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/headius/invokebinder/1.13/invokebinder-1.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/headius/options/1.6/options-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jzlib/1.1.5/jzlib-1.1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.12.5/joda-time-2.12.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/me/qmx/jitescript/jitescript/0.4.1/jitescript-0.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/headius/backport9/1.13/backport9-1.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-stdlib/9.4.5.0/jruby-stdlib-9.4.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/4.0.0/maven-reporting-api-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-exec/2.0.0/maven-reporting-exec-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.4.2/maven-shared-utils-3.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/3.6.2/maven-archiver-3.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.27/plexus-interpolation-1.27.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/4.10.0/plexus-archiver-4.10.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/3.5.0/plexus-io-3.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.26.2/commons-compress-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.17.0/commons-codec-1.17.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/io/airlift/aircompressor/0.27/aircompressor-0.27.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.9/xz-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/luben/zstd-jni/1.5.6-3/zstd-jni-1.5.6-3.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-10/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.1/plexus-utils-4.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-xml/3.0.1/plexus-xml-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/2.0.0/doxia-sink-api-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/2.0.0/doxia-core-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-text/1.12.0/commons-text-1.12.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml5/2.0.0/doxia-module-xhtml5-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/2.0.0/doxia-module-apt-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/2.0.0/doxia-module-xdoc-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/2.0.0/doxia-module-fml-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-markdown/2.0.0/doxia-module-markdown-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark/0.62.2/flexmark-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-builder/0.62.2/flexmark-util-builder-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-collection/0.62.2/flexmark-util-collection-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-dependency/0.62.2/flexmark-util-dependency-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-format/0.62.2/flexmark-util-format-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-html/0.62.2/flexmark-util-html-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-visitor/0.62.2/flexmark-util-visitor-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-data/0.62.2/flexmark-util-data-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-misc/0.62.2/flexmark-util-misc-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-sequence/0.62.2/flexmark-util-sequence-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-ast/0.62.2/flexmark-util-ast-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-abbreviation/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-abbreviation-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util/0.62.2/flexmark-util-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util-options/0.62.2/flexmark-util-options-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-autolink/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-autolink-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/nibor/autolink/autolink/0.6.0/autolink-0.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-definition/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-definition-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-escaped-character/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-escaped-character-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-footnotes/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-footnotes-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-gfm-strikethrough/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-gfm-strikethrough-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-tables/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-tables-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-typographic/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-typographic-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-wikilink/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-wikilink-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-yaml-front-matter/0.62.2/flexmark-ext-yaml-front-matter-0.62.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/25.0.0/annotations-25.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[82] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-model/2.0.0/doxia-site-model-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[83] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.9.0.M3/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.9.0.M3.jar
[ERROR] urls[84] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/2.1.0/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[85] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/2.0.0/doxia-site-renderer-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[86] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-skin-model/2.0.0/doxia-skin-model-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[87] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/2.2.0/plexus-velocity-2.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[88] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity-engine-core/2.4/velocity-engine-core-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[89] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/tools/velocity-tools-generic/3.1/velocity-tools-generic-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[90] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[91] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[92] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[93] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-digester3/3.2/commons-digester3-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[94] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/cliftonlabs/json-simple/3.0.2/json-simple-3.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[95] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-integration-tools/2.0.0/doxia-integration-tools-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[96] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.17.0/commons-lang3-3.17.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[97] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-server-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[98] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[99] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-io-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[100] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-http-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[101] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-servlet-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[102] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-security-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[103] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util-ajax/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[104] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-webapp-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[105] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-xml-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] urls[106] = file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.4.56.v20240826/jetty-util-9.4.56.v20240826.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

Any ideas?

Looks like you're missing a dependency or you have incompatible versions.

I might succeed using the doxia 3.1.1 version instead of 3.0.0
